# Multiplication table in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to know if I'm too far off here, I want to have a form, in this case a multiplication table and have Javascript compare the results and show if it's correct or not (I realize this code may seem grotesque to some of you but I'm new to this and this is a self imposed exercise).

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>

<form id="myForm">

    </h3> 2 * 1 = </h3> <input id="one" type="text" name="1" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 2 = </h3> <input id="two" type="text" name="2" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 3 = </h3> <input id="three" type="text" name="3" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 4 = </h3> <input id="four" type="text" name="4" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 5 = </h3> <input id="five" type="text" name="5" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 6 = </h3> <input id="six" type="text" name="6" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 7 = </h3> <input id="seven" type="text" name="7" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 8 = </h3> <input id="eigth" type="text" name="8" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 9 = </h3> <input id="nine" type="text" name="9" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    </h3> 2 * 10= </h3> <input id="ten" type="text" name="10" maxlength="4" size="2"><br><br>

  <input id="submit" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit Form">
```

```
  <h1 id="results"> Results</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
var one = document.getElementById("one").value;
var two = document.getElementById("two").value;
var three = document.getElementById("three").value;
var four = document.getElementById("four").value;
var five = document.getElementById("five").value;
var six = document.getElementById("six").value;
var seven = document.getElementById("seven").value;
var eight = document.getElementById("eight").value;
var nine = document.getElementById("nine").value;
var ten = document.getElementById("ten").value;

var results = document.getElementById("results");

function myFunction() {
var submit = document.getElementById("submit").submit();
   if (one === 2 && two === 4 && three === 6 && four === 8 && five === 10 &&  six === 12 && seven === 14 && eigth === 16 && nine === 18 && ten === 20) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Correct!"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Try Again!"
    }
 };
```

Comment: Nice code, but what is the question?

Comment: Ahh, well it doesn't work : )

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Well, like i say in the description, I would like to have a form and have Javascript compare it's values and display a right or wrong message. As of right now it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Is there an error in the logs? Anything to indicate an error? Or is really /nothing/ happening when you click the button?

Comment: Look at the errors in your browser's JavaScript  console.  There's  at least one misspelling that should cause some errors to be logged.

Comment: I can see it saying that "myFunction" is not defined.

Comment: Have you included your JavaScript in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, it did change the innerHTML of the h1 before when testings it. the console says that myFunction is not defined but I don't really see the problem.

Comment: Where have you included it? Is the code you have shown a snippet of your HTML, or is it all of it in its entirety?

Comment: I'm using CodePen, it's not necessary to add it.

Comment: Your h3 tags are incorrect, copy and paste error?  Also you don't have an element with an id of results and don't know why you submit again at the start of your submit function: `var submit = document.getElementById("submit").submit();`.  And you need to prevent the form from actually submitting to see the js result

Comment: If this is on CodePen, could you make your Pen public and share it with us? That way we would be able to debug it directly.

Comment: The answer below works, but just not in CodePen, it works in Plnkr for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is What Your are expecting

```js
function myFunction() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one").value;
var two = document.getElementById("two").value;
var three = document.getElementById("three").value;
var four = document.getElementById("four").value;
var five = document.getElementById("five").value;
var six = document.getElementById("six").value;
var seven = document.getElementById("seven").value;
var eight = document.getElementById("eight").value;
var nine = document.getElementById("nine").value;
var ten = document.getElementById("ten").value;

var results = document.getElementById("results");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
   if (one == 2 && two == 4 && three == 6 && four == 8 && five == 10 &&  six == 12 && seven == 14 && eight == 16 && nine == 18 && ten == 20) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Correct!"
    } else {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Try Again!"
    }
 }
```

```css
h3{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
  </head>

  <body>
<form id="myForm">

    <h3> 2 * 1 = </h3> <input id="one" type="text" name="1" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 2 = </h3> <input id="two" type="text" name="2" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 3 = </h3> <input id="three" type="text" name="3" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 4 = </h3> <input id="four" type="text" name="4" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 5 = </h3> <input id="five" type="text" name="5" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 6 = </h3> <input id="six" type="text" name="6" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 7 = </h3> <input id="seven" type="text" name="7" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 8 = </h3> <input id="eight" type="text" name="8" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 9 = </h3> <input id="nine" type="text" name="9" maxlength="4" size="2"><br>
    <h3> 2 * 10= </h3> <input id="ten" type="text" name="10" maxlength="4" size="2"><br><br>

  <input id="submit" type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit Form">
  
    <h1 id="results"> Results</h1>
    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That does work yes. So putting the vars inside the function and removing the .submit()...Thank you, I'll try to understand what i did wrong, but I guess I was kinda "close".

Comment: @Sergi - you also needed to use `==` instead of `===`. Using `===` isn't a syntax error, but you are comparing numbers with strings so you need `==` to get automatic type coercion.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var i=0;
var n=prompt("enter a number:")
var str="";
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="0">');
for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    document.write("<tr><td>" + n + " x " + i + " = " + n*i + "</td></tr>");
}
 document.write("</table>");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="myFunction()">
<p id="msg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

or else use this for particular two numbers:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var n=prompt("enter a number 1:");
var i=prompt("enter a number 2:");
var str="";
document.write("output is :"+ n + " x " + i + " = " + n*i);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="myFunction()">
<p id="msg"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very nice but it writes the table complete, I wanted the user interaction and basically to know if i was getting close to display if the user was right or wrong. It's pretty genius but way above what I can grasp, been studying for just a month. Thank you though.